# CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis возвращает 0

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

Добавил канвас и кнопки для него, для движения по оси X. Сделал все по мануалу, но не двигается по этой оси. Не двигается через нажатия на кнопки, но через установленных в InputManager "a", "d", "left", "right" объект двигается.

Создал новый проект для тестинга, но все равно ничего не получается

[image: Скрипт обьекта]

Comment: Что еще Вы сделали с кнопками, кроме того, что добавили их на Канвас? Какие обработчики событий указали? Или через компонент EventTriggers?
Уточните, пожалуйста, какой код выполняется при нажатии на кнопки?

Comment: Я использовал скрипт из импортированного CrossPlatformInput - Axis Touch Button. Этот скрипт я добавил кнопкам.